# Appcompat style error in Android Studio 0.8.2 (beta)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I' ve checked previous questions about Appcompat resource not found questions but non of them solves my problem. I've added appcompat 20.0 to my project as a library and checked whether it is in external libraries folder or not. I 've also checked dependencies in build.gradle and it is also there .But whenever I try to create new style in styles file IDE cannot find @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light. Any Suggestions ?

what I am trying to do (gives errors)

```
<style name="Theme.myactionbar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    items
    ...      
</style>
```

On the other hand ,I can  easily enable theme from manifest under application tag without problem

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: appcompat 20.0 not fully supported yet by AndroidStudio, I had many bugs with 20.0 version. many errors if you try to compile project using support 20.0 libraries, designer won't work with 20.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue but for me its only IDE issue. When I run the app it work with right theme